# SQL CASE Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, case-statement

Is the following possible in SQL Server 2000?

```
CREATE FUNCTION getItemType  (@code varchar(18))
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
Declare @Type tinyint
Select @Type = case len(@code)
WHEN 12,14,17 THEN 1
WHEN 13,15,18 THEN 2
WHEN 8,10 THEN 3
ELSE  0
END
RETURN (@Type)
END
```

Thanks.

Comment: What happened when you ran that in SQL Server 2000?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
Select @Type = 
(select case 
WHEN len(@code) IN (12,14,17) THEN 1
WHEN len(@code) IN (13,15,18) THEN 2
WHEN len(@code) IN (8,10) THEN 3
ELSE  0
END)
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I did this a long time back but couldn't remember...couldn't find on msdn either and also BOL.

Comment: take a look at Dave Markle's solution below - he uses the same case syntax but tightened up the syntax of the function itself

Answer (score 6):

This should do it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getItemType(@code VARCHAR(18))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CASE 
        WHEN LEN(@code) IN (12,14,17) THEN 1
        WHEN LEN(@code) IN (13,15,18) THEN 2
        WHEN LEN(@code) IN (8,100)    THEN 3
        ELSE  0
    END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 try  
  SELECT CASE
           WHEN LEN(@gcode) IN(x, y, z) THEN a  
         END
 etc.
```

or you may need

```
SELECT CASE LEN(@gcode)  
         WHEN x THEN a  
         WHEN y THEN a  
       END
```

etc.

[Here's the reference.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)